# ReadDocumentAsync always fails claiming Id does not exist

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I am querying Azure DocumentDb (cosmos) for a document that is present in the container:

```
try{
   doc = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(
   GetDocumentUri("tenantString-campaignId"),
       new RequestOptions 
       {
          PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(tenantString)
       });
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
   } 

 for this document:
```

[image]

tenantString-campaignId is the id you can see here and tenantString alone is the partition key this is under. The tenant itself was passed in as a string and I had that working but now I have changed to passing a Tenant object and parsing the string required from it I am not returning the document.

I have tried a few different variations of tenantString and id and I can generate either a DocumentClientException, Id does not exist, Exception or it fails silently; no exception and returns to the calling method where it causes a NullReferenceException as no document is returned.

As far as I can make out from debugging through this I am constructing all my data correctly and yet no document is returned. Does anyone have any idea what I can try next?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your code: what is `GetDocumentUri()` doing? Is that something you've written? I can't find that method in the SDK.

Comment: Also, please edit your question to contain formatted text for your sample document, instead of an image. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) for the many reasons why this is really important.

Comment: One thing you could try to do is trace the request/response through Fiddler and see what's being sent over the wire.

Comment: Does GetDocumentUri use UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri using the correct database and collection names, and the id?

Comment: Sorry all I have been creating the url incorrectly. Not from the db/collection point of view but passing the wrong combination for the id of the record. That is the getdocumenturi call, which is correct I was just passing the wrong thing to it. Thanks all for giving your time to look at this for me but in the end it was just a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax for the .NET SDK v2 is not correct. ReadDocumentAsync() should look like this.

```
var response = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseName, collectionName, "SalesOrder1"), 
    new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Account1") });
```

You can see more v2 samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-samples#document-examples)